# Ignore mocked child-objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I wonder if there is a way to ignore child-objects with NHibernate where a mapping with cascading does exist. Given following situation: A super-admin is allowed to see all events, even though he is not inscribed in all of them. This is achieved with mock (or fake) - objects representing relationship between super-admin and events, which do not exist on persistence-level.

The only problem is that NHibernate would create these mock - objects as new entries if the super-admin is saved. Is there a way to register these child-objects somehow in order to make NHibernate ignore them?

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a design like so:

```
public class User
{
    private IList<Event> _events;
    public IList<Event> Events
    {
        get { return IsSuperAdmin ? Event.All : _events; }
    }
}
```

Then your mapping could map only to the field _events rather than the public property.

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be no way to tell hibernate something like this. I do it now similar to your suggestion.